# Compare time of day using Euclidean distance

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have $t_1, t_2, ..., t_N$, where each $t \in [0, 1[$ is a time during the day (i.e. 0.01 is right after midnight and 0.99 is right before midnight). I want to compute the distance between these time of day such that I can identify times that are close to each other.

The distance should wrap around midnight such that times right before midnight and right after midnight are close (constraint 1 below). The distance between two points should also be such that a time twice as far away should have twice the distance (constraint 2 below).

The tricky part is that because this time comparison will be part of an existing [nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) solution, the distance metric has to be Euclidean distance (L2).

To put it more mathematically:

- $t \in [0, 1[$
- $f(t)$ maps $t$ to a vector of dimension $f_d$
- $d(f(t_1), f(t_2))$ is the Euclidean distance between $f(t_1)$ and $f(t_2)$

These are the constraints we're trying to achieve:

1. $d(f(t_1 + \Delta, 1), f(t_2 + \Delta, 1)) = c$ for all $\Delta \in [0, 1]$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant
2. $d(f(t), f(t + k \cdot \Delta)) = k \cdot d(f(t), f(t + \Delta))$

These two constraints could probably expressed in a simpler way. If so, feel free to try to reformulate them!

**Own attempt**

I tried mapping the time onto the unit circle, i.e. $f(t) = (\sin(t), \cos(t))$. This fulfills constraint 1 as the Euclidean distance between two points on the unit circle is the [chord length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)), which only depends on the angle and thereby wraps around the midnight point at 1. However, this approach doesn't fulfill constraint 2 above as a time twice as far away does not have twice the distance, e.g. $t=0.25, \Delta=0.25, k=2$ such that $d(f(0.25), f(0.75) \ne 2 \cdot d(f(0.25), f(0.5))$.

Comment: You introduce $f$ with one argument but then in $1$. you use it with two arguments. Is there a typo?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done.

First of all, you don't actually want constraint 2 as stated, because of the wraparound: you want the distance between $0$ and $3\cdot \frac25$ to equal $\frac15$, not $3\cdot\frac25=\frac65$.

But even confining to situations where you want this literal statement, one can derive a contradiction. For example, consider the images $f(0),f(\frac25),f(\frac45),f(\frac65)=f(\frac15)$:

- The (Euclidean) distance between $f(0)$ and $f(\frac25)$ should equal the distance between $f(\frac25)$ and $f(\frac45)$, and the distance between $f(0)$ and $f(\frac45)$ should equal twice this distance. These constraints force $f(\frac25)$ to be the midpoint of the segment from $f(0)$ to $f(\frac45)$ (by the law of cosines, if you like).
- Similarly, $f(\frac45)$ is forced to be the midpoint of the segment from $f(\frac25)$ to $f(\frac65)=f(\frac15)$.
- But again, $f(\frac15)$ is forced to be the midpoint of the segment from $f(0)$ to $f(\frac25)$.

And these three facts are incompatible with one another. (Well, if $f$ is a constant function then I guess it works, but I doubt that's what you want.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to adjust my constraints to make them better reflect what I'm looking for. If you ignore my ill-conceived constraints and only my written text, do you still conclude that it can't be done?

Answer (score 1):

If we consider $0 \le t_1 \le 1$ and $0 \le t_2 \le 1$, with $0$ and $1$ indicating the same position, then
$$d(t_1, t_2) = \min\bigr( \lvert t_2 - t_1 \rvert,~ \lvert t_2 - t_1 + 1 \rvert,~ \lvert t_2 - t_1 - 1 \rvert \bigr), \quad 0 \le d \le \frac{1}{2}$$
is the wraparound Euclidean distance between $t_1$ and $t_2$.  Note that this can be calculated using
$$\begin{aligned}
t_{+} &= 1 + t_2 - t_1 \\
d(t_1, t_2) &= t_{+} - \lfloor t_{+} \rfloor \\
\end{aligned}$$
where $\lfloor~\rfloor$ denotes truncation or rounding down (say, `floor()`).

Another way to define the same function is
$$d(t_1, t_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\arccos\biggr(\cos\Bigr(2\pi (t_2 - t_1) \Bigr)\biggr)$$
which has the interesting feature that
$$\cos\varphi = \cos\Bigr(2\pi (t_2 - t_1)\Bigr)$$
where $\varphi$ can be considered an analog of the "angle" between two one-dimensional wraparound Euclidean values $t_2$ and $t_1$.

Comment: Thanks @None! However, unless I've misunderstood something, you're defining a distance metric? As mentioned in my original post, the distance metric has to be L2 norm due to this solution being used for NN search.

Comment: @pir: So, what you actually need, then, is a $d(t_a, a_1, \dots, a_n, t_b, b_1, \dots, b_n)$ metric where the $t$ dimension is wraparound (modular, $[0,1[$), and the others flat, it sounds like.  It is demonstrably impossible to construct a flat Euclidean space using vector-valued function $f(t_1, a_1, \dots a_n)$ where $t$ dimension is wraparound, and $a_1$ through $a_n$ flat, that has an $L_2$ norm.  You can't have a finite radius circle whose perimeter is a straight line, you see, or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I really like the example in your last line - that makes a lot of sense to me :)